# How do you tame Minecraft Ocelots when they don't eat?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

When I try to tame the ocelots, nothing happens. I have used all of the types of fish-both cooked and raw- and still nothing happens.

Answer (score 2):

With the new 1.14 update you can no-longer tame ocelots but rather you need to find a stay cat in a village, the taming process is just the same though, (approaching the cat slowly with fish). I recommend having 5-10+ fish on you.

Comment: [Ocelots will only enter a "trust" mode](https://minecraft.gamepedia.com/Ocelot#History) instead of being "tamed" in 1.14. They can still be bred, as per normal.